# Android error dialogfragment with toast dialoginterface

Tags: android, toast, dialogfragment

have this code i only need show one toast if click accept or cancel,but cant understant why is wrong
how can fix? error is on toast `getapplicationcontext()`
im learn about dialogs and toast on android

```
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class confirmacion extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage("Confirmar?").setTitle("confirmacion")
        .setPositiveButton("aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    Log.i("dialogos","aceptado");
    dialog.cancel();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Eliminacion fallida.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }


        }).setNegativeButton("cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    Log.i("dialogos","cancelada");
    dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        return builder.create();

    }

    }
```

Comment: try to pass `getActivity()` into `Toast.makeText(getActivity()....).show();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change from

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Eliminacion fallida.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

to

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Eliminacion fallida.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: can some one tell me why `getActivity()` used  over here?

Comment: because in Fragment getApplicationContext() not applicable. For that you have to use Fragment context or getActivity().

Comment: that's what i m talk in about.thnx

Comment: @SimplePlan your wel come...!!

Comment: thanks very much, I hope anyone else that will be of use

Comment: @Cazs Wel come...Glad to help you!!